# A game of n players

Tags: game-theory

> There are *n* players. Each player has to choose an integer. The
>   winner is the one with the lowest integer that has not already been
>   chosen by another player.
>
> What is the optimal strategy?

*e.g.* if there are 3 players and 2 choose the same number, the winner is the third player. However if all three choose a different number, the winner is the one who has chosen the lowest integer.

Comment: I believe this is a pretty well known problem.  For example: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80714/game-theory-unsure-how-to-proceed-with-this-question) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_bid_auction) would solve it... So I am voting to close this since it is a math question and not a puzzling question.

Comment: @kaine uhh, I think it's only similar... this one is any $n$ while that one is $0<n<6$

Comment: @Hugh this is asking for a more general case of that question without adding anything more to it.  That question made for a good puzzle.  Expanding it to any value of n does not make for a good puzzle though a very good math topic.

Answer (score 0):

> I recommend playing this on a computer.

because

> first of all, press - and hold down the 9 key until you’ve got at least a page.

then

> copy that page (don’t be dumb and copy the minus sign), and begin spamming command-v (the paste button)

When you feel like it,

> copy the entire thing, and continue pasting until your computer dies to lag. Congratulations!

What I’m trying to say is

> it doesn’t have to be a positive integer, so go wild with negatives.

So, the winner will always be

> the person with the best computer.

Comment: What if I say rot13("artngvir vasvavgl")?

Comment: @Dorrulf (rot13) V qba’g guvax Vasvavgl vf na vagrtre...

Comment: Yeah, I was considering that too. But it's a short hand representation of what you're doing ;)

Comment: This answer would have been quite suitable for a comment

Comment: @Bass that's quite a lot to put in a comment, and I'd have to rot13 a majority of it, but... okay...

Comment: This answer also shows why this is not a duplicate :)